# Port-Forwarding page shows nothing (CenturyLink)

Tags: router, port-forwarding

There are several threads on this website on how to properly do port-forwarding with CenturyLink routers ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/1023829/my-repeater-is-not-letting-me-port-forward), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/807472/port-forwarding-actiontec-gt784wn-with-centurylink-static-ip) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/622951/centurylink-c1000a-router-trouble), as examples.)

My issue is that I can't even see anything on my port-forwarding page. Specifically, when I go to port forward page, I see an empty page: [image]

Any thoughts why this is happening?

Comment: Something similar to this happened to me recently - my router seemed to automatically sign me in as a guest for some reason. Have you checked that you're signed into the main account for your router? Some accounts don't allow you to view or change any settings on your router.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after restarting my router.